gdbserver not passing all environment variables to debugged process
Looking at /proc/pid/environ for both gdbserver and the debugged process I see that not all variables are passed to the debugged process. Some are missing. Is this a bug? Or normal?
The debugged process has not yet jumped to main; gdbserver is waiting for gdb but already created the process. So it is not my code that removes variables (I am not doing this anyway).

I would be very surprised if gdbserver really removed variables. Maybe you could show how you start the program, and what variables are missing.

Sure, first, I check the list of variables using xargs -0 -L1 -a /proc/<pid>/environ for both gdbserver and the child. I start gdbserver (in a script) with gdbserver.cross-ng tcp:$GDBPORT $processname $@ &. The name of the variable is DBG-TANG, which I see in gdbserver but not the child

Could it be because of the - in the environment variable name?

This all depends on how you are setting the environment variable.  GDB doesn't try to forward everything in its environment through to gdbserver, this might work for you, but would be wrong in other cases, sometimes the remote is a very different type of target.  However, if at the GDB prompt you do set environment VAR VALUE then GDB should forward this to the remote target.  Similarly, if you unset environment VAR GDB should forward this to the remote.  If you are doing these and it's not working then add your GDB session details (commands typed) to the question.

The envar were set locally before starting gdbserver. Nothing remote. The funny thing is that this is random; using the xargs above does not list the variables in the same order for both process. In anycase, the missing var was the first in the list for gdbserver.As for the - I will have to give it a try.
